# how to make trigger in rethinkDb

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

**My Requirement :**

When ever there is a data change in a table(s) (whether insert,update,delete) , i should be
able to update my cache using my logic which does manipulation using the table(s).

```
Technology : Node, rethinkDb
```

**My Implementation :**

I heard of `table.changes()` in rethinkDb, which emits a stream of objects representing changes to a table.

I tried this code

```
r.table('games').changes().run(conn, function(err, cursor) {
  cursor.each(console.log);
});
```

Its working fine, i mean i am getting the events in that i put my logic for manipulations.

**My Question** is for how long it will emit the changes  .. I mean is there any limit.
And how it works ?

I read this in their doc,

***The server will buffer up to 100,000 elements. If the buffer limit is hit, early changes will be discarded, and the client will receive an object of the form {error: "Changefeed cache over array size limit, skipped X elements."} where X is the number of elements skipped.***

I didn't understand this properly. I guess after 100,000 it wont give the changes in the event like old_vale and new_value.

Please explain this constraint and also as per requirement will this work ?

I m very to this technology. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: There's no limit.

The 100.000 elements for the buffer is if you do not retrieve changes from the cursor. The server will keep buffering them up to 100.000 elements. If you use `each`, you will retrieve the changes as soon as they are available, so you will not be impacted by the limit.